# Why can't Cursive identify Java methods in Clojure code?

Tags: clojure, cursive

This code works just fine.

```clj
  (.. svc (projects) (search) (setQuery filter) (setPageToken tok) execute)
```

(See also screenshot.)

It seems that the IDE has all the type-info it needs since `svc` is type-hinted as [`CloudResourceManager`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager/latest/).

So why can't the syntax highlighting  identify `projects` and other methods, and why does the inspection say  "...cannot be resolved"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue that's been there for quite some time now: https://github.com/cursive-ide/cursive/issues/321